# What does it mean when a function $f$ has a subscript that is an indexing set $A$? That is, $f_A$.

Tags: functions, notation

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

I'm having trouble understanding certain notation he uses for a particular problem. To put it into context, here is the problem at hand

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces and set $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha.$ For each $\alpha\in A$ let $f_\alpha:I\to X_\alpha$ be a path in $X_\alpha$. Set $(f_A(t))(\alpha)=f_\alpha(t)$ so that $f_A:I\to X$. Show that $f_A$ is a path in $X$.

I don't necessarily need any help with this problem yet, because I haven't even tried it. I looked through the book for that type of notation, but was unsuccessful. Could someone please point out what the definition for $f_A$ is? Is it specific to this problem or a general type of notation?

Comment: He defines it in that thing you wrote. It is a map from $I$ to $X$ defined as it says.

Comment: I see. Thank you guys for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Mendelson is doing here is this: $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of functions, one for each $\alpha \in A$. We can fix $\alpha$ and vary $t$, which is to look at each function individually. *Or* we can fix $t_0$ and vary $\alpha$, giving us a different value $f_\alpha(t_0)$ for each $\alpha \in A$. For each $t\in I$, we get a bunch of values (in fact we get $|A|$ of them), each one living in it's own space $X_\alpha$. Another way of saying this is for each $t \in I$, we get an *element* in $\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha = X$ (since an element in $\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ is a set of values, each living in its own space $X_\alpha$). So $f_A:I \to X$ is a function taking each $t$ to a set of values, one for each $\alpha \in A$.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the answer, it cleared somethings up.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $f_A$ is right in the text you quoted:

> Set $(f_A(t))(\alpha)=f_\alpha(t)$ so that $f_A: I\to X$.

Comment: It seems like that notation would imply that each output of $f_A$ is a function, not a point in $X$. Can you explain what the $(\alpha)$ at the end of LHS is doing?

Comment: Is it similar to an indexing on the individual functions $f_\alpha$, $\alpha\in A$?

Comment: @EricStucky The product has probably been defined as the set of maps from $A$ to the disjoint union of the $X_{\alpha}$ such that the image of any $\alpha\in A$ is in $X_{\alpha}$.